# What does it mean? "being into someone"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I was reading a book and there was a sentence in it  :

> Are you into me?

It was like a romantic dialog but i don't know the exact meaning.    So i have 2 questions:
1. What does it mean?
2. I think it means "Do you love me?" . If this meaning is right, which one is more polite? "I love u" or "I'm into you" ? What's the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*to be into something* means that you are very interested in it. For example (and the following examples are very typical uses of this expression, by the way):

> I'm into computers.

This means that you're very interested in the field of computer technology. You have lots of computers at home, you read books about operating systems, programming languages and things like that. In other words, you're a computer buff.

Another example:

> Sorry, I'm not gay. I'm only into girls.

This means that you're only interested in dating girls and not men because you are heterosexual.

---

> Are you into me?

Here, the person probably wants to know whether the other person he or she is talking with has feelings of romantic love for them. Basically, she or he wants to know if the other person likes her or him (in other words, wants to know if the other person is interested in them romantically).

---

Simply put, *I'm into you* is a slang way to say *I love you*.

Comment: "I'm into you" is a lot less strong than "I love you".

Comment: what about "you're into me now for some serious cash" , what does that mean?

Comment: That probably means that she shows her affection for the guy, but that's because he's got money.

Comment: Trey, I think "You're into me for some serious cash" has NOTHING to do with interest or affection. It means, "You've borrowed money from me many times in small amounts, and the total amount you owe me is a large (serious) amount." I think it implies that the speaker is tired of being used as an ATM and wants the borrower to stop asking and maybe even pay back some money.

Answer (score 4):

This person is obviously saying they like you. "I'm into you" which is stating that they like you and interested in you.